# Angular js routing issues with transitions how could that be eliminated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

***> transition suspended,prevented,aborted,failed in angular ui-routing..... anyone could you please help me?....I am using angular 
 1.6.4 version and ui-router's version is v0.2.18...***.js

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

app.config(['$qProvider', functi;on ($qProvider) {  
    'use strict';   
$qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false); }])
```

Comment: Refer this : https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld

Comment: what  is the problem behind those errors prevented,aborted,failed,suspended....unable to find  the solution...searching on that since yesterday.....even  using above code failed to remove the errors ....and thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I've never seen such errors, Can you paste screenshot of it?

Comment: Error: transition superseded
    at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2903)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
    at angular.js:4795
    at d (angular.js:4944)
    at e (angular.js:4969)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4995)
    at angular.js:8110
    at q (angular.js:403)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:8108)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

Comment: unable to paste it ..once check out your mail..i ll send you the screenshot

Comment: Can you check this : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3246

Answer (score 0):

I find out the error behind the transition suspended, prevented, aborted and failed in angular ui-routing.

These errors may occur when you forget to implement the states & controllers of respective ui-sref and also I have changed the version of ui-router from 0.2.8 to 0.3.2.

I hope this might help someone.